# Calculate odd and even averages of whole numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I need to write a program to calculate the even and odd average of whole numbers input by the user. The user types “done” to complete. The output will show the average of the odd numbers, and the average of the even numbers.

I have my while loop program that does the sum of the numbers, and I'm trying to add the additional requirements of an odd sum and even sum to. Here is that code:

```py
total = 0
done = False
while(not done):
    user_in = input("Give me an integer or type 'done' to be done.")
    if( user_in.lower() == "done"):
        done = True
    else:
        # assume that they've typed in an integer
        total += int(user_in)
print (total)
```

Below is my modified code to sort odd and even numbers, then average each group.

```py
total = 0
evenSums = 0
oddSums = 0
done = False
while(not done):
    user_in = input("Give me an integer or type 'done' to be done.")
    if( user_in.lower() == "done"):
        done = True
    else:
        # assuming they've typed in an integer
        total += int(user_in)
        if user_in % 2 == 0:
            evenSums += user_in
            evenAverage = evenSums / user_in
        else:
            oddSums += user_in
            oddAverage = oddSums / user_in
print(total)
print("Even Average: " + str(evenAverage))
print("Odd Average: " + str(oddAverage))
```

Expected:

```
Enter number: 11
Enter number: 24
Enter number: 18
Enter number: 29
Enter number: 7
Enter number: done
Even Average: 21
Odd Average: 15.666666666666666
```

Actual:

```
Give me an integer or type 'done' to be done.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/guita/Documents/School/CSCI100/CSCI100_Lab4_P/CSCI100_Lab4_P/problem7.py", line 14, in <module>
    if user_in % 2 == 0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user_in` is a string, therefore you cannot take its modulo. Do `int(user_in) % 2` instead..

Answer (score 0):

You should convert `user_in` to a number before you perform arithmetic operations on it. You should also keep track of the counts of even numbers and odd numbers separately in order to calculate to right averages for each:

```
evenSums = 0
oddSums = 0
evenCount = 0
oddCount = 0
done = False
while not done:
    user_in = input("Give me an integer or type 'done' to be done.")
    if user_in.lower() == "done":
        done = True
    else:
        user_in = int(user_in)
        if user_in % 2 == 0:
            evenSums += user_in
            evenCount += 1
        else:
            oddSums += user_in
            oddCount += 1
print("Even Average: " + str(evenSums / evenCount))
print("Odd Average: " + str(oddSums / oddCount))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if user_in % 2 == 0:
```

On the previous line, `int(user_in)` **does not** cause `user_in` to become an integer. It creates a **new** value, which is the integer equivalent.

As a result, the `%` is interpreted as the string formatting operator rather than a modulo operator, and the error message is exactly as you'd expect.

Replace `user_in` with its integer equivalent first, and then do all the appropriate operations and tests with it:

```
user_in = int(user_in)
total += user_in
if user_in % 2 == 0:
    # etc.
```

Additionally:

```
evenAverage = evenSums / user_in
```

There are two logical errors here (and similarly for `oddAverage`). First, you need to divide by the *number of* even numbers that was input, not by the most-recently-input even number. You will have to count separately how many even numbers were input. Second, this division must happen *only once, after* all the numbers were input - therefore, it does not belong inside the loop.